# Quasar Framework how to store login hash so that it works on web and mobile ( using cordova ) application

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, quasar

I am working on a web and mobile app using https://quasar.dev which is VueJs framework. My main dilema is how do I write the code so universal that for example the login functionality work on both web and mobile. For my backend I am using Laravel with Passport, so after successful login I get a hash. The problem is **where do I store this hash ?**

I have read this page https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-ssr/ssr-frequently-asked-questions and it says that Local Store doesn't work while SSR. And they say you can import Cookie and it will be sent on every request. Then where do I store the hash on mobile ? and how do i deploy in on cordova? using ssr or without ?

So to sum up my questions:

1. Where do I store the hash ? Different places on web and mobile ?
2. When deploying on ssr I run npm `run build --mode ssr` and the `npm run start` in the build-ssr folder and on mobile `npm run build` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in the local storage or use vuex-persist https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist to make a store that is stored in the local storage. also local storage works on Cordova! https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html

To the second question if you are using the Quasar Cli you should use the Cli commands to build for mobile and web. https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-ssr/build-commands#Building-for-Production  https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-cordova-apps/build-commands#Introduction